# Child Class names in logger

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class LogMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, log_name, log_level=logging.INFO):
        self.project_name = self.__class__.__name__
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.log_name = log_name
        self.log_file_path = (r"\\Logging\\{}_{}.log".format(self.log_name, datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")))
        self.logger = self._get_logger()

    def _get_logger(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.project_name)
        logger.setLevel(self.log_level)
        fh = logging.FileHandler(self.log_file_path)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        fh.setLevel(self.log_level)
        ch.setLevel(self.log_level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)12s - %(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.info("START")
        return logger

    def log(self, log_line, severity=None):
        self.logger.log(severity or self.log_level, log_line)

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = pyodbc.connect("")
        self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()

    def query_df(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
        return self.fetchall()


class Query(Database, LogMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        LogMixin.__init__(self, project_name='final-project')

    def main_query(self):
        self.log('Test query', severity=logging.DEBUG)
        df = self.query_df(sql="")
        return df 


class Processing(Query):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def main_df(self):
        df = self.main_query()
        self.log("Beginning processing")
        return df 


class Wrangling(Processing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def data_wrangling(self):
       self.log("Wrangling data")
       df2 = self.main_df()
       return df2


wr = Wrangling()
wr.data_wrangling()
```

I am attempting to create one log file at the end of the process in this format:

```
INFO - 2022-10-26 15:27:46,761 - START

Query - DEBUG - 2022-10-26 15:27:46,761 - Test Query

Processing - INFO - 2022-10-26 15:28:46,761 - Beginning processing

Wrangling - INFO - 2022-10-26 15:29:46,761 - Wrangling data
```

My current approach creates this output:

```
Wrangling - INFO - 2022-10-26 15:27:46,761 - START

Wrangling - DEBUG - 2022-10-26 15:27:46,761 - Test Query

Wrangling - INFO - 2022-10-26 15:28:46,761 - Beginning processing

Wrangling - INFO - 2022-10-26 15:29:46,761 - Wrangling data
```

How can I make the names in front of the log message to be specific to the class that it's coming from instead of just the class where the process is started from?

Comment: Your implementation of a logging class is very troublesome. You could have done it without a logging class. Anyway let me write a solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of classes is a bit troublesome. Avoid calling a separate `_get_logger` and `log` methods entirely

```
class LogMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, log_name="", log_level=logging.INFO):
        self.project_name = parent.__class__.__name__
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.log_name = log_name
        self.log_file_path = (r"\\Logging\\{}_{}.log".format(self.log_name, datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")))
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.project_name)
        logger.setLevel(self.log_level)
        fh = logging.FileHandler(self.log_file_path)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        fh.setLevel(self.log_level)
        ch.setLevel(self.log_level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)12s - %(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.info("START")


class Query(Database, LogMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        logmix = LogMixin(self)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logmix.project_name+'.Query')

    def main_query(self):
        self.logger.info('Test query')
        df = self.query_df(sql="")
        return df 

class Processing(Query):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def main_df(self):
        df = self.main_query()
        self.logger.info("Beginning processing")
        return df 


class Wrangling(Processing):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def data_wrangling(self):
    self.logger.info("Wrangling data")
    df2 = self.main_df()
    return df2


wr = Wrangling()
wr.data_wrangling()
```

Will return

```
NoneType - INFO - 2022-10-26 22:04:21,491 - START
Wrangling - INFO - 2022-10-26 22:04:21,492 - START
Wrangling.Query - INFO - 2022-10-26 22:04:21,492 - Wrangling data
```